# SHOW CREATE TAG fails in NebulaGraph database

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm testing with NebulaGraph database version 3.1.2 and NebulaGraph Explorer version 3.2.0.

When running `SHOW TAGS`, I could see the tag `Comment` listed. But when I tried to run `SHOW CREATE TAG Comment`, the console returned `-1005:Tag not existed!` I don't understand why that is happening.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So weird that I can `SHOW CREATE` other tags such as `SHOW CREATE Forum`.

Comment: Could you try adding the escape charactor ` to bracket the `Comment`?

Comment: Ah, it works Wey! Thank you! Could you post an answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: "Comment" is a keyword in the NebulaGraph database. Now I got it.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that when you were creating the tag `Comment`, somehow your client changed its case to `comment`,(thus to suggest add `) and didn't realize it's actually a keyword to be escaped in such a case. posted as an answer then, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with @randomv in comments, it turned out `Comment` is a keyword in NebulaGraph, thus we need to escape it with `, then the lines should be:

```
SHOW CREATE TAG `Comment`;
```